# cloudera agent start fail, Failed to connect to previous supervisor

Tags: cloudera

I am installing cloudera. I have success to start cloudera-server. But When I start cloudera-agent, logs shows the following error.

> [15/Aug/2016 03:41:41 +0000] 114598 MainThread agent        ERROR
>   Failed to connect to previous supervisor. Traceback (most recent call
>   last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/cmf/agent/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cmf-5.8.1-py2.7.egg/cmf/agent.py",
>   line 2039, in find_or_start_supervisor
>       self.get_supervisor_process_info()   File "/usr/lib/cmf/agent/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cmf-5.8.1-py2.7.egg/cmf/agent.py",
>   line 2185, in get_supervisor_process_info
>       self.identifier = self.supervisor_client.supervisor.getIdentification()   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1233, in **call**
>       return self.__send(self.__name, args)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1587, in __request
>       verbose=self.__verbose   File "/usr/lib/cmf/agent/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor-3.0-py2.7.egg/supervisor/xmlrpc.py",
>   line 460, in request
>       self.connection.request('POST', handler, request_body, self.headers)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 979, in
>   request
>       self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1013, in _send_request
>       self.endheaders(body)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 975, in endheaders
>       self._send_output(message_body)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 835, in _send_output
>       self.send(msg)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 797, in send
>       self.connect()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 778, in connect
>       self.timeout, self.source_address)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
>       raise err error: [Errno 111] Connection refused

I have try both methods  PlanB and PlanC, they shows the same error.
I am sure the following

1. my server is listening in 7182
2. cloudera-agent machine can access server machine.
3. my hosts is configured correct.

Because I use curl cloudera-master:7182 to test connection the sever machine,results shows it connect success and my hosts is correct.

> **root@cloudera-node1:/home/tuomao# curl cloudera-master:7182 
>      Error 405 HTTP method GET is not
>   supported by this URL
>
> ### HTTP ERROR 405
>
> Problem accessing /. Reason:
>
> ```
>     HTTP method GET is not
> supported by this URL
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Powered by

I have search all the answers from the Internet,but still can't locate the error place.Can can one  help me to solve it?